# Javascript - Two different objects in the same canvas

Tags: javascript, html, oop, canvas

I am coming from AS3 OOP to HTML5 and this kinda confuses me;

I have this code(it works so far):

```
<canvas id = "ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

<script>

var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");

ctx.font = '30px Arial';        
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';       
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;  

ctx.fillText('Hello',50,50);   

</script>
```

From what I understand, inside the < script > we "import" the canvas Object in the first line, then we set it's properties and draw the text in the following lines. So now, everytime I do

```
ctx.fillText();
```

It will inherit the font, size and style properties of the ctx object and draw new text.

Now, I am trying to create a new object like this:

```
var x1 = new Object();
x1.fillText('Hello',1,50);
```

It doesn't do anything, I am trying to create this object in order to avoid the Inheritance of the properties from the ctx object(style, font etc).
I'd appreciate some new info about this kind of OOP, and thank you for your time.

Comment: you're just creating a new `Object` (nothing to do with canvas) - that object wont have a `fillText` method

Comment: Why not? care to explain how would it have the same functions as the canvas?

Comment: Because an object doesnt have that method. If you wrote the same code in AS3 would you expect it to magically have a `fillText` method?

Comment: of course not... i'd have to  use a class which will inherit these kind of methods, probably directly from a sprite class. How do I make it inherit this kind of functions in Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

A good source of reference for all things javascript is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) and in your case the page you're after is titled [Applying styles and colors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors) [to canvas]

The relevant section is

> Note: When you set the strokeStyle and/or fillStyle property, the new value becomes the default for all shapes being drawn from then on. For every shape you want in a different color, you will need to reassign the fillStyle or strokeStyle property.

I would assume that the same applies for `font`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create a new object which you define, so a `textobject` would store it's string, position, etc etc

Then you can just create a textObject like you create a class or an object.

Here is a simple example jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/bbfgmpvk/1/

Javascript

```
   var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");

textObject = function(textValue, fontValue, fillStyleValue, xValue, yValue)
{
    this.text = textValue;
    this.font = fontValue;
    this.fillStyle = fillStyleValue;
    this.xPos = xValue;
    this.yPos = yValue;
}

textObject.prototype.Draw = function()
{
    ctx.save();

    ctx.font = this.font;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.fillStyle;
    ctx.fillText(this.text, this.xPos, this.yPos);

    ctx.restore();
}

var textObject1 = new textObject("Hello there", "30px Arial", "#000", 50, 50);
var textObject2 = new textObject("So you want some?", "25px Arial", "#333", 150, 150);
var textObject3 = new textObject("... Text", "20px Arial", "#555", 300, 300);
textObject1.Draw();
textObject2.Draw();
textObject3.Draw();
```

Comment: This is a great example, it might help the OP if you explicitly allow the font/fillStyle to be passed in on the constructor. - otherwise its no different to their current way.